# can't get progressdialog to show with async await method

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin, async-await

I'm trying to have a progress dialog show while the app is saving to the database.  I'd like to do it using the async await keywords but I can't get the progress dialog to show.  Do I have to add some run on ui thread syntax to this?  What's the easiest most succint way to add progress dialogs to async methods on my button onclick event?

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);
    SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

    Button button_submit = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.button_submit);

    button_submit.Click += async (object sender, EventArgs e) =>  {
        using (ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.Show (this, "Please wait...", "Saving Data", true))
        {
            try
            {
                await this.SaveData();
            }
            finally{
                progressDialog.Dismiss();
            }
        }


    };
}
```

Here's the SaveData method

```
private async Task<bool> SaveData(){


    try{
        //Validate ();

        string connectionString = "Foo"

        SqlConnection dbcon;
        using (dbcon = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {

            await dbcon.OpenAsync();
            using (SqlCommand dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand()) {

                //MERGE UPSERT
                string sql = "bar"

                dbcmd.CommandText = sql;
                dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", this.scanId);

                dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@lat", this.geo[0]); 
                dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@lng", this.geo[1]);
                dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@timestamp", this.timestamp);
                      //commented out to test to make sure slow file io isn't the issue
                //byte[] imageBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes (photoUri.Path);
                //dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@photo", imageBytes);

                var result = await dbcmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

                if (result != 1)
                    throw new Exception("Save encountered an error " + result);
            }
        }
        //ResetData ();
        RunOnUiThread(() => Toast.MakeText (this, "Data Saved", ToastLength.Long).Show ());
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        RunOnUiThread(() => Toast.MakeText (this, ex.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show ());
        return false;
    }



}
```

Comment: How does your original code behave if you replace `await this.SaveData()` with `await Task.Run(() => SaveData())`?

Comment: that lets the progress show up correctly but on the Dismiss() method I get the error "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"

Comment: Since `Task.Run` did let the progress show up, that indicates that `SaveData` is not actually asynchronous (as @Servy commented). Your problem is in `SaveData`.

Comment: I see the error is from a toast that is not in a RunOnUiThread as well I just wrapped that and it looks like the progressdialog is showing correctly.  Will try removing the task run now and see.

Comment: If you correctly fix the `async` `SaveData` method, then you won't need `RunOnUiThread` *or* `Task.Run`.

Comment: just added the savedata method to the description, it looks async to me, can't see where it's making it run synchronously

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey You're reading in an entire file's contents synchronously.  That's potentially quite time consuming.  It should be done asynchronously.

Comment: You're right.  I deleted the file io and the validate and reset data methods to test but still seems to be causing the same issues..

Answer (score -2):

Try this inside button click .. this is very simple

```
ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
progress.Indeterminate = true;
progress.SetProgressStyle(ProgressDialogStyle.Spinner);
progress.SetMessage("Loading... Please wait...");
progress.SetCancelable(false);

RunOnUiThread(() =>
{
    progress.Show();
});
Task.Run(()=>
//here savedata method
).ContinueWith(Result=>RunOnUiThread(()=>progress.Hide()));
```